# How to install docker's btrfs volume plugin?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

When run command:

```
docker run -it -v some_volume:/abc/xyz --volume-driver=btrfs a_docker_image /bin/bash
```

terminal shows:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: create some_volume: Error looking up volume plugin btrfs: plugin not found.
```

====================

But if create volume first:

```
docker volume create --opt type=btrfs --name some_volume
```

It will create volume successfully.  Now if I try to run container and create a new volume:

```
docker run -it -v some_volume:/abc/xyz --volume-driver=btrfs a_docker_image /bin/bash
```

It shows (of course it makes sense, since the same name volume has been already created):

```
docker: Error response from daemon: create some_volume: conflict: volume name must be unique.
```

And if I try to run container with the existing volume:

```
docker run -it -v some_volume:/abc/xyz a_docker_image /bin/bash
```

It returns:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: missing device in volume options.
```

====================

Could anyone help tell me how to install the **volume plugin btrfs** for docker?  I haven't found any useful information regarding that except some introduction about plugin (but not how to install).  Thanks in advance.

As suggested by @forevergenin in comments, here is my docker environment:

`docker version`

```
Client:
 Version:      1.11.0
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   4dc5990
 Built:        Wed Apr 13 18:13:28 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.0
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   4dc5990
 Built:        Wed Apr 13 19:36:04 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

`docker info`

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 39
Server Version: 1.11.0
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 121
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null host bridge
Kernel Version: 4.1.19-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.11.0 (TCL 7.0); HEAD : 32ee7e9 - Wed Apr 13 20:06:49 UTC 2016
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 996.1 MiB
Name: default
ID: 74TB:OVH5:S3GD:UQUG:ILWG:5NVH:2MSH:5H7R:A5H4:GSLV:2Q6D:ZIR6
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 15
 Goroutines: 32
 System Time: 2016-08-15T13:57:03.866016657Z
 EventsListeners: 0
Username: thyrlian
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
```

Comment: Can you share more information on the environment ? like the docker version, host os you are running (linux, macOS or windows - which version), etc. You can get these information by running `docker version` command.

Comment: thanks @forevergenin , I've added both `version` and `info` outputs.

Comment: Thats great ! I see you are running OS X. I am also running my setup on OS X but I am running `docker version 1.12` and I don't face any issues when I tried to create a btrfs volume. `docker volume create --opt type=btrfs --name test_volume` creates volume without any issues. If possible try upgrading `docker` to `version 1.12`. If you are using `homebrew` do you can do that by running `brew cask install docker`.  Or you can download native version of docker for OS X from https://www.docker.com/products/docker#/mac .

Comment: @forevergenin my problem is not about `docker volume create` (it could create volume without any issue), it's about `docker run --volume-driver=btrfs` (it tells plugin not found).

Comment: How do you tell docker where the btrfs volume is? I see your "Storage Driver" is "auf" (`docker info` output). When you run `docker volume create`, is the resulting volume a btrfs subvolume?

Comment: By the way, I have the exact same behavior as you do, but my "Storage Driver" is "btrfs"

Comment: Thanks @JonesV .  I didn't tell docker where the volume is.  I thought it should manage that by itself when using `docker volume create`.  And `docker volume ls` doesn't support printing verbose information, so that I can't tell if the newly created volume is indeed **btrfs** or not.  Did you mean that you get the same error even if your storage driver is already **btrfs**?  It's unbelievable hard to sort this problem out, I couldn't really find any useful documentation about how docker volume create work.

Comment: I'm not sure which btrfs volume plugin you're talking about, I didn't find a real working one so I started that : https://github.com/anybox/buttervolume

Answer (score 1):

I am new to btrfs with docker, but here is my understanding:

Using btrfs as a storage driver means that docker will use btrfs internally for the images and containers (that is explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/btrfs-driver)). Specifically, look at the installation details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/btrfs-driver/#/configuring-docker-with-btrfs): they make you create a btrfs partition and mount `/var/lib/docker` on it. When you restart your docker daemon after that, `docker info` should tell you "Storage Driver: btrfs".

Using the btrfs driver, the image's base is saved int `/var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes`, and then they do snapshots (but I am not sure where they save them exactly). But that is done automatically without you specifying the driver (I would guess that specifying the driver is useful when you have multiple drivers that can run on a given filesystem. But the btrfs driver seems to be the default when /var/lib/docker is formatted in btrfs.

Regarding volumes, I believe that they are not saved as btrfs subvolumes. They seem to be simple folders in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`. Again, I can imagine this as being the normal behavior of docker: images and containers are layered, but volumes are simple directories.

At least, that is the behavior I observe:

- If I pull an image or create a container, I get btrfs subvolumes created.
- I could create a volume by simply using `docker volume create testvol1` and mount it in a container. But then it is not a btrfs subvolume.

If you want to have your volumes in btrfs subvolumes, then I believe that you might need to create the subvolumes manually and mount the volumes in them directly.